# Excel VBA Using Call procedure to loop

Tags: excel, vba

Any suggestions on the best practice to Call the procedure would be greatly appreciated.  Have tried to set it on OnSelectionChange with no success.  The DocumentComplete includes an END which is necessary to stop the Application.Speech from repeating.  Below is the code.

```
Sub AutoDomain()
'HOW TO LOOP?
    Dim xURL As String
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Application.Speech.Speak "Starting Look Up", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    xURL = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Cells(1, 3).Value = ""
    Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Cells(1, 3).Borders.Color = xlNone
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = ""
    WebBrowser1.Silent = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate (xURL)
    Sheets(1).Calculate
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    WebBrowser1.Stop
    URL = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Cells(1, 3).Value = WebBrowser1.LocationURL
    Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Cells(1, 3).Borders.Color = vbRed
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = "DOMAIN : " & WebBrowser1.LocationURL & vbCrLf & "TITLE  : " & WebBrowser1.LocationName
    Do Until Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value <> ""
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Speech.Speak " Look Up Completed ", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    End
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the overall goal of the above and with a loop? If you are calling the bottom sub from the top where will  pDisp and URL come from?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to loop through a list of URLs.  Sorry, the pDisp and URL were not removed, as the URL is derived from the actual cell value.

Comment: So, is the bottom sub relevant?

Comment: Necessary to determine when the webbrowser completes.

Comment: But you don't call it in the top sub.

Comment: Correction pDisp and URL are dependent upon the actual webpage retrieved, as the URL is derived from the actual cell value.

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768329(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Aha..... that is me told. Thanks.

Comment: So, you just want a loop over cells picking up new URLs?

Comment: Yes, and Call the top Procedure.